# How to highlight 2017 in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, conditional-formatting

I need cells in Excel to be highlighted if they contain 2017 in the date. For instance there is a column that has just dates. Some dates are for 2017. I need to input those dates at a later time.

The column with approved vacation for the year and includes some dates for 2017. I've tried the Highlight Cell with text that contains "2017", "m/dd/2017", "mm/dd/2017". What am I doing incorrectly?

Comment: More information is required to answer your question.

Comment: @Ramhound What additional information could you possibly be seeking?  Jane: [info on Excel date highlighting](https://blogs.office.com/2013/04/04/using-conditional-formatting-to-highlight-dates-in-excel/#GHMAiHcjYHApieJI.97) seems to provide multiple optins.  Any of them any good for you?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include some example (mock) data (before and after). See [Format Text as a Table](http://www.sensefulsolutions.com/2010/10/format-text-as-table.html) for a web utility that will help you to create a nice data table you can paste into your question.

Comment: Thank you for your comments.  Yes, it is in an excel spreadsheet.  Column with approved vacation for the year and includes some dates for 2017.  I've tried the Highlight Cell with text that contains "2017",  "m/dd/2017", "mm/dd/2017"  What am I doing incorrectly?

Answer (score 1):

Use the conditional formatting FORMULA option.  Assuming your test cell is A1 the formula would be `=YEAR(A1)="2017"`

The problem you will be having is that Excel is converting your dates to an integer value (the number of days since 00/01/1900) then displaying them in the form "mm/dd/yyyy"; 01/01/2017 is stored as 42736.  Conditional formatting for "contains 2017" thus won't work.